# How to collectively send the parameter to a Python function and collect the result in list?

Tags: python

I try to write a function `func_apply(func_name, **kwargs)` that receive the `func_name` and parameter values in list, then apply the parameter one by one to `func_name` , collect the result and return as a list. I need this high order function `func_apply` mainly to abstract the syntax, for my application often need to apply different parameter values to various functions and collect the result in a batch.

```
def my_minus(x,y):
    return x-y

def my_divd(a,b):
    return a/b

def func_apply(func_name, **kwargs):
    '''apply the parameter in kwargs one by one to func_name,
       collect and return result in a list.
       for example: 
         func_apply(my_minus, x=[2, 4, 5, 7], y=[1, 4, 3, 9]) will return [1,0,2,-2], 
         func_apply(my_divd,  a=[2, 4, 5, 7], b=[1, 4, 3, 9]) will return [2,1,1.66,0.77]
    '''
    # the codes
```

So, how to write the `func_apply` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `zip` and a `list comprehension`:

`kwargs` is a dict here, as dicts don't have any fixed order so you may have to get a sorted list of values first based on the keys.

```
>>> from __future__ import  division   # not required in py3.x
def func_apply(func_name, **kwargs):
    vals = [kwargs[key] for key in sorted(kwargs)] #sort the keys lexicographically
    return [func_name(*x) for x in  zip(*vals)]
... 
>>> func_apply(my_minus, x=[2, 4, 5, 7], y=[1, 4, 3, 9])
[1, 0, 2, -2]
>>> func_apply(my_divd,  a=[2, 4, 5, 7], b=[1, 4, 3, 9])
[2.0, 1.0, 1.6666666666666667, 0.7777777777777778]
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. The problem is that func_name might need various number of parameter. For example: def my_cal(a,b,c): return a/b-c  . then hard code return [func_name(x,y) for x,y in  zip(*vals)] not work for such case.

Comment: @bigbug solution updated. use `func_name(*x) `, take the advantage of sequence unpacking.

Comment: Yeah, pretty and concise solution. Thanks

Comment: I appreciate the clever tip of sorting the kwarg first, for I spend a lot of time to figure out how to match and construct the parameter name (x=2, y=1 etc) and pass to the func_name.

Comment: More general solution (which, for example, would support a function ``my_divd(y, x)``) would involve ``Signature.bind()`` from the ``inspect`` module (Py3 only, or with the help of ``funcsigs`` module from PyPi).

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary, I found an issue with your solution today, That it assumes the parameters of function called are defined in alphabet ascending order, otherwise, the kwarg will mismatch. The sample is, def my_minus(y,x):    return x-y . Then  func_apply(my_minus, x=[2, 4, 5, 7], y=[1, 4, 3, 9]) gives wrong result [-1, 0, -2, 2].

Comment: @bigbug It's not a bug, I clearly mentioned that in the answer. *sort the keys lexicographically*

Comment: @bigbug It can be fixed if you always use x,y as the variable name, because using `a,b` is the reason I had to sort it.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary, I know It is not a bug,  I just want to use "func_apply" to various functions of real application, and the arguments of the function are not always defined in  alphabet ascending order (Actually most of time , they are not). So "func_apply" needs to find a way to handle this issue.